# How to show google map marker(s) whose radius encompass target marker?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps

I am racking my brain on this problem. I have a database of store locations, each has a latitude, longitude, and radius. What I am after is to display a map with a given center (user's location), and IF that user's location falls within any of the radius of the store locations' radius, show those stores. If a store radius does not touch the center (user's location) do not show the store.

I am currently using IP GEO LOCATION to get the ip address of the visitor, and return a latitude and longitude. Then with the users location, I query the database as such:

```
select s.street, s.city, s.latitude, s.longitude, s.radius, sa.north, 
sa.east, sa.south, sa.west from shops as s inner join service_areas as sa on 
s.id = sa.shop_id where 32.931354 between sa.south and sa.north and 
-97.095583 between sa.west and sa.east
```

The values of north, south, east, west are generated from this php script I had someone do years back.

```
<?php

include "dbconnect.php";

$query="select id, latitude, longitude, radius from shops where state = 'Colorado';";
$rs=$mysqli->query($query);

while($r=$rs->fetch_object()) {
$sho_id=$r->id;
$lat=$r->latitude;
$lng=$r->longitude;
$radius=$r->radius;
$north=-90;
$east=-180;
$south=90;
$west=180;

$circlePolygon=createCirclePolygon($lat,$lng,$radius);

$polygon=array();

foreach($circlePolygon as $cPoint) {
if($cPoint['lat']<$south) $south=$cPoint['lat'];
if($cPoint['lat']>$north) $north=$cPoint['lat'];
if($cPoint['lng']>$east) $east=$cPoint['lng'];
if($cPoint['lng']<$west) $west=$cPoint['lng'];
$polygon[]=implode(",", $cPoint);
}
$polygon=implode(" ", $polygon);
$fields="shop_id=$sho_id, north=$north, south=$south, east=$east, west=$west, polygon='$polygon'";
$query="insert into service_areas set $fields on duplicate key update $fields;";
$mysqli->query($query);
if($mysqli->error) {
echo "ERROR: $mysqli->error\n";
}
echo "done<br/>";
}
echo "complete";

function createCirclePolygon($lat, $lng, $radius) {
$pointArray=array();
$d2r = pi() / 180;
$clat = ($radius / 3963.189) / $d2r; // miles
$clng = $clat / cos($lat * $d2r);
for($ang=0;$ang<=360;$ang+=10) {
$a=$ang*$d2r;
$plat=$lat+($clat*sin($a));
$plng=$lng+($clng*cos($a));
$point=array("lat"=>$plat,"lng"=>$plng);
array_push($pointArray,$point);
}
return $pointArray;
}
?>
```

I had thought this was working until I ran the above query. If you look at the attached image you will see a blue marker (the user) that is not in any of the radius of the red markers. The only time a red marker should show is if it's radius touches the blue marker. (the radius around the red markers is being generated by javascript using only the latitude, longitude, and radius values)

[image: Texas Shops]

Finally, if you look at the attached screen shot of my database, you'll see I have coordinates for north, east, west, and south that are generated by the above script. But what puzzles me is the target marker's (blue) latitude and longitude DOES fall within the north and south, east and west values. This leaves me to wonder if the script generating the coordinates for the circle(s) around each marker is not correct.

[image: Database Screen Shot]

Comment: Your formula is checking a square bounds (although that isn't the only problem), you need a geographic query on distance..

Comment: Thank you. I should mention that the screenshot of the table does not show a column the programmer created called polygon that is in addition to the north, south, east, west. Maybe the fact that I took the idea of simply using the between operator for mySQL against the four values and am not using the polygon is the part of the issue(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to find all shops that have a users location within their radius? If yes, please try this query (untested).

```
SELECT s.street, s.city, s.latitude, s.longitude, s.radius, sa.north, sa.east, sa.south, sa.west, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(32.931354) ) * cos( radians( s.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( s.longitude ) - radians(-97.095583) ) + sin( radians(32.931354) ) * sin( radians( s.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM shops AS s
WHERE distance <= s.radius
```

You will need to replace the values accordingly.

The query uses the [haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) and I quote from Wikipedia:

> The haversine formula determines the great-circle distance between two points on a sphere given their longitudes and latitudes.